# Extracting Data from NSKeyedArchiver in Non-ARC Code

Tags: objective-c, memory, nskeyedarchiver

In my non-ARC iOS project, I have a method that returns archived data:

```
- (NSData*) archivedData {
    NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    // Encode the fields that must be archived:
    [archiver encodeObject:... forKey:...];
    ...
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [archiver release];
    return [data autorelease];
```

Since `initForWritingWithMutableData:` is deprecated, I modified the implementation:

```
- (NSData*) archivedData {
    NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initRequiringSecureCoding:YES];
    // Encode the fields that must be archived:
    [archiver encodeObject:... forKey:...];
    ...
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    NSData* data = [archiver encodedData];
    [archiver release];
    return data;
```

At first, I called `autorelease` on the encoded `NSData` object before returning it but that resulted in a bad memory access (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). Everything seems to work fine without `autorelease`.

I am now confused. Since I release the archiver before returning the data, I thought `autorelease` would protect the `NSData` object, deallocating it not before it is processed by the calling method. I worried that the `NSData` object might be deallocated right after the archiver is released without the `autorelease` call. Somehow, the opposite happens when I run the code.

Could anybody please shed some light on this behavior?
Also, if I'm doing something wrong, I'd like to know how to fix the code.

I'm aware of the static method `archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:` but I can't easily use it because I don't have a root object as I encode objects individually. Using a root object would break compatibility for existing users of the app (if I understand it correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData* data = [archiver encodedData];
```

The method `-encodedData` does not begin with `alloc` or `new`, nor does it include the word `copy`, nor it it called `retain`. That means you did not take ownership of it. You must not call `release` on it. It doesn't belong to you. Said another way: you have not put a retain on this object; you must not call release on it.

You then release `archiver`, which was responsible for `data`. There is no promise that `data` exists anymore. The fix for this is to retain it before releasing `archiver`:

```
NSData* data = [[archiver encodedData] retain];
```

This is the effectively the same thing the original code did by initializing `data` using `+[NSMutableData alloc]`. Note the word "alloc." This gives ownership (a retain) to `data`.

By the same naming conventions, this method promises to return an object that the caller doesn't need to release. (It's often easiest to think of this as having a net retain count of 0, but there are many cases where that isn't strictly true.)

```
- (NSData*) archivedData { ... }
```

You have put a retain on the `data`, so you need to balance that out. You want the object to survive long enough to be returned, however. The fix for that is `-autorelease`, just like in the original code:

```
return [data autorelease];
```

So all together:

```
- (NSData*) archivedData {
    NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initRequiringSecureCoding:YES];
    // Encode the fields that must be archived:
    [archiver encodeObject:... forKey:...];
    ...
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    NSData* data = [[archiver encodedData] retain]; // Retain here
    [archiver release];
    archiver = nil; // It's good practice to nil values that are no longer valid
    return [data autorelease]; // autorelease here
}
```

I can't find Apple's helpful Memory Management Rules page anymore, but it's summarized in [Three Magic Words](https://robnapier.net/three-magic-words).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer! Your code sample makes perfect sense and works as intended. However, I still don't fully understand why there's an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when the object is autoreleased without retaining it. What happens to the object?

Comment: Sending an object `-autorelease` means that when the autorelease pool drains (usually at the end of the event loop), the object will be sent a `-release`. If the object has already been destroyed, then that message will be sent to a dangling pointer, which is undefined behavior, but in most cases will crash with an exception. In simpler terms, "autorelease" is just "a release in the future" and if you release more than you retain, you crash. (If you retain more than you release, you (generally) leak memory.)